# Floating content box in text like and image [css]

Tags: html, css, block, css-float

I know this is probably a simple question but my mind just isn't working this morning! Basically I have a box with content in it (like a content/at a glance box) and I want to float it with some text like you would float an image. Right now the following CSS is doing this:

[image: picture of what's happening]

How would you go about fixing this?

**CSS**

```
#content #info_box {
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #efefef;
}
#content #info_box #content {
  width: 210px;
  margin: 7px 10px;
}
#content #info_box #content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 3px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#content #info_box #content ul li {
  background-image: url(/images/arrow_bullet.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 5px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
#content #info_box #content #dates { font-size: 14px; }
```

**HTML**

```
    <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna tincidunt congue sed ut dui. Morbi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis consequat. Vivamus id mollis quam. Morbi ac commodo nulla. In condimentum orci id nisl volutpat bibendum. Quisque commodo hendrerit lorem quis egestas. Maecenas quis tortor arcu.</p>
<div id="info_box">
    <div id="content">
        <b>Job at a glance</b>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li>This job is an internship</li>
            <li>It pays $7 per hour</li>
            <li>You'll be working 3 hour shifts</li>
        </ul>
        You'll be scheduled to work on:<br>
        <span id="dates">S <b>M</b> <b>T</b> <b>W</b> <b>T</b> <b>F</b> S</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#content #info_box #content` makes no sense. That's looking for an element with id `content` inside an element with id `info_box` inside an element with id `content`.

Comment: Where should the grey box be? At the top-right of the paragraph? Top-right? At the left?

Comment: Thirtydot, I'd love to see the markup required to get the box to display in the top-bottom. ;)

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski: Yeah, typo :) Here you go: `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0` :p

Comment: @thirydot, using absolute layout is not recommeded since it donesn't work in all browers .

Comment: @Alaa: Sure it works, unless you care about Internet Explorer Version Ancient. More to the point, that was a joke about a typo, *why on earth* would you comment on it?

Comment: @thirtydot +1 for pwnage and IE™ StoneAge™

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/qfzJ2/1/

You had an extra `#content` at the start of all your classes

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks Myles!

Answer (score 1):

simply give `float:right` in the *#info_box*. Why have you written `margin-left` in *#info_box* two times?

Comment: That was a Less CSS thing because of the grid I was using. I'll try the float:right, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand u want to place the #info_box to the right of p so 
give a fixed width for p and float it to left and float the #info_box to the right.